# Images Elaboration Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, elaboration

I'm trying to do this but I don't find any solution.

I have this image A

[image: imageA]

and I would like to have the same white areas in this image B

[image: image B]

How can I do this in Matlab?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Unable to write a full answer right now, but assuming the two images are the same size, you're looking for something along the lines of `imageB(rgb2gray(imageA) >= 254,:) = 255;`, which takes imageA, converts to grayscale, finds what pixels are white, and then sets those pixels in image B to white.

Comment: yes, they have the same size in terms of pixels. If you can explain me it better, I would be grateful.